# what's the bestway to export the list of 200 Environment variables systematically to all the users in the puppet agent node , will hiera be useful?

Tags: environment-variables, puppet, centos7, hiera

I have an RPM whose installation I want to manage with Puppet.  At installation time it depends on the values of 200 environment variables, which values differ from system to system and may change over time.  What is the best way to proceed? Is it better to use Hiera or ERB templates in Puppet for changing and versioning the environment?

I am new to Puppet, but got a bit of an idea on how to do it. I want to know the most efficient way of exporting such a large number of environment variables.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "exporting environment variables in the puppet agent deployment".

Comment: I mean to keep the variables in the Environment which will be available for all the users who use the puppet agent machine.

Comment: Hiera and templates are not alternatives to each other.  They have orthogonal scope and use cases.  What system state are you actually trying to manage?  It can't be environment variables themselves, because those are per-process properties, not system properties.  Indeed, there is no way to force any variable to always be in every process's environment, but there are ways you could put environment variables into users' initial shell environments.

Comment: @JohnBollinger my actual use case is I want to install a program using rpm which needs some of the environment variables to be present for it to be installed. that is the requirement I have

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what you're actually trying to manage.  Moreover, it adds a new, important ambiguity: do you need the environment variables *for installation to succeed* (which would be surprising) or *for using the software* (or both).  Also, do you need all 200 variables for a single piece of software, or a few each for many different pieces of software?

Comment: I need the environment variables to make my software know it has to be installed in certain way for the certain environments and it's for the single piece of software.

Comment: Ok.  Ridiculous, but ok.  And is Puppet responsible for installing the software, too, or is that to be done manually in the environment configured for it by Puppet?

Comment: Yes puppet is responsible for configuring and installing the software too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first, long-term best bet is to have the RPM packaging and / or the packaged software itself redesigned so that its *installation* is completely independent of any environment variables.  This is far and away the norm, and anything else is deeply problematic for most everyone, Puppet notwithstanding.  The software can adjust its *runtime* behavior however you like under the influence of environment variables, but its installation should be insensitive to them.

Yet I anticipate that you'll deny that being a possibility.  In that case, you need to understand that no matter how you configure the system to provide environment variables in users' sessions, Puppet exercises good security practices by controlling the environment of external commands it launches, such as package management commands.  Therefore, you will not be able to use a `Package` resource to manage (installation of) your RPM if you need to influence its installation via environment variables.

I would recommend using Puppet to manage an installation script for the RPM that exports all the wanted environment variables and then runs `yum` to install the RPM.  Or if you must, then also manage a local copy of the RPM file and have your script use `rpm` to install it.  If you need the environment variables *only* at installation time then they can go straight into the script; otherwise, you probably want to set them up via environment setup files in `/etc/profile.d/software_name.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/software_name.csh`.  Either way, a template, whether ERB or EPP style, would be a good way to write the file(s) containing the environment variable definitions.  Then use an `Exec` resource to run the script when appropriate.

Hiera is a separate question.  Note well that normally, Hiera is used only on the master, during catalog compilation, not on client machines.  You can absolutely store the environment variable values in an external Hiera data file, and look them up at catalog building time.  I would definitely recommend it.  Depending on how exactly you set that up, it could make the template(s) I suggested a lot simpler to implement.  For example, you could feed the template a hash from variable names to variable values, and iterate over it to emit all the needed variable definitions -- much better than 200 lines of separate variable definitions and a corresponding 200 or more lines in your manifest file.